# unable to override volume mount with docker-compose.override

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to spin up a local version of a web app on my Mac and I need to tell docker-compose not to attempt to mount certain volumes.  I am using a `docker-compose.override.yml` file, but what I am doing is apparently not overriding anything.

Here's the relevant part of my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    volumes:
      - user-data:/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/static/images/data
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt

  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./web/flask_brain_db/static:/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/static
      - user-data:/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/static/images/data
      - /etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
```

Here's the relevant part of my `docker-compose.override.yml`:

```
 web:
    volumes:
      - user-data:/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/static/images/data

  nginx:
    volumes:
      - ./web/flask_brain_db/static:/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/static
      - user-data:/usr/src/app/flask_brain_db/static/images/data
```

When I run `docker-compose up` I still get the error associated with attempting to mount that letsencrypt drive.  If I actually go and physically comment those lines out in `docker-compose.yml` I no longer get that error.

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Based on this: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3729 and that: https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3939 I do not think this can work. At least it seems compose can't "remove" just overwrite and add.

Comment: "Just don't do it this way" is helpful, thanks!  I'll structure the config files differently.

Comment: but in previous versions it did work '(
I was using it a lot for large jekyll sites when develop new templates.
In docker-compose version 1.24.1, build 4667896b is not working